# curl request in bash script that requires a dollar sign in the URL

Tags: linux, bash, curl, escaping, urlencode

I have a problem that I just cannot seem to solve.

I need to make a curl request to a given URL, and the URL requires a dollar sign in it.

So, for example:

> www.example.com/mypath/function&$filter=whatever

Now, I can execute this just fine from the command line if I put the URl in single ticks, or if I escape the dollar sign with a backslash, and then put it in a double quote.

Obviously, there is a problem if you do not do either of the above, because bash will see the '$' and will interpret anything after it to mean a variable name.

So when I try:

```
URL="www.example.com/mypath/function&\\\$filter=whatever"
MYOUTPUT=$(curl -s --header "Authorization: $HEADER" "$URL")
```

it doesn't work right.

When I try

```
URL="www.example.com/mypath/function&\$filter=whatever"
MYOUTPUT=$(curl -s --header "Authorization: $HEADER" "'$URL'")
```

it doesn't work right.

What am I doing wrong?

I can tell it's not working right because the server is not responding the same way in the script as it does in the command line.  The site responds in a certain default manner if the query isn't done right, and I always get the default response through the script.

Comment: Can you give me the question I am duplicating?  Yeah, folks have asked questions about curl and scripting, but I haven't seen anything about how to deal with a rogue dollar sign.

Answer (score 2):

If you put a literal `$` in a string, bash will not try to interpret it in future expansions:

```
URL='www.example.com/mypath/function&$filter=whatever'
MYOUTPUT=$(curl -s --header "Authorization: $HEADER" "$URL")
```

Comment: What happens if I want to put a variable in the $URL?

Comment: @jasonmclose It's fine. You can either escape the `\$` in double quote, or mix&match quotes with `'URL='etc/$filter='"$myvar"`

Comment: So I got this to work kinda using what you said.  So <URL='https://www.example.com...'"$VAR"'&$filter=whatever'>, and then using putting the URL variable in double quotes.

Comment: I think SO mangled that